# what is arduino when using bridge between device and hardware(actuators)?

Tags: ros2, arduino

When Arduino simply provides a target value according to a command,

Is this the same as a controller? Or is it called controller manager?

If I configure Arduino as a node and deliver a message,

What is the controller here?

Comment: is this a school assignment?  ... what research have you done?

Comment: @jsotola No. I am in the process of connecting to hardware, and I uploaded this to check if I understood it correctly while looking for how to configure it.